# What idioms can describe a tough or difficult thing (such as a test)?

Tags: phrases, idioms

An easy test (or similar undertaking) might be described as

> 'a piece of cake'

Are there any idioms to describe a test (etc.) that is difficult?

Comment: Anjan- I have edited your question in an attempt to make it more clear.  If I have misinterpreted your question please feel free to rollback my changes and update it as you see fit.

Comment: "Ordeal by fire" !

Comment: Looking at the original question, it seems clear that the OP wants an idiom that's an antonym for *a piece of cake,* which *describes* tasks, such as a test.

Comment: You can say it *wasn't* a piece of cake.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that by "*question paper*" you mean *test*.

In that case a tough test might be described:

> The test was ***a [real] bear***

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear):

> ***bear*** : 4.  something difficult to do or deal with- *< the oven is a* bear *to clean* >

Comment: This is rather a North American idiom, as bears don't really feature in other English-speaking parts of the world. [Black bears](http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/naturelibrary/images/ic/464x261/a/am/american_black_bear/american_black_bear_map.gif) | [brown bears](http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/naturelibrary/images/ic/464x261/b/br/brown_bear/brown_bear_map.gif)

Answer (score 3):

> *The test was a ____________!*

***[Nightmare](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nightmare)***.

> 2.1 A person or situation that is very difficult to deal with:
>
> **OED**

A few other nightmarish experiences are applied metaphorically:

*[Headache:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/headache)*

> 1.1 informal
>
> A thing or person that causes worry or difficulty; a problem:
>
> **OED**

*[Pain in the neck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pain+in+the+neck)* (and a few other less noble parts of the human anatomy)

> something or someone that causes trouble;
>
> a source of unhappiness;
>
> Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton
> University, Farlex Inc.
>
> **thefreedictionary.com**

*[Can of worms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+of+worms)*

> Fig. a very difficult issue or set of problems;
>
> an array of difficulties. (*Typically: be ~; Open ~.)
>
> **thefreedictionary.com**

*[Snake pit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snake+pit)* might have connotations that drag you away from the difficulty of a test but there is surely a metaphorical intersection in the word picture:

> any place of pain and turmoil;
>
> **thefreedictionary.com**

The final two definitely have connotations in another arena, but the word pictures apply metaphorically:

*[Hornet's nest](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hornets%27+nest)*

> A situation that presents difficulty, uncertainty, or perplexity:
>
> **American Heritage® Dictionary** of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing
> Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
> All rights reserved.

*[Pandora's box](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pandora%27s+box)*

> n.
>
> A source of many unforeseen troubles:
>
> **American Heritage® Dictionary** of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing
> Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
> All rights reserved.

Comment: I'm with you on *nightmare* and *Pain in the neck*, but I'm not sure that *can of worms* and *hornet's nest, *Pandora's box* etc. mean difficult.  Rather, they mean something you don't want to get into; something best left undisturbed.

Comment: I have found with these requests that going up to the edge of the semantic field produces good results for the qeust.

Comment: You are not worth another word, else I'd call you **knave**!

Comment: It may be good and useful to give related  idioms, but I think they should be labelled as such. We will not, for example, use *can of worms* to mean difficult when describing a test.

Comment: "...connotations that drag you away from the difficulty of a test but there is surely a metaphorical intersection in the word picture." I don't see how connotations would drag anyone away from a difficulty. It is not clear what a "word picture" might be here, and so certainly not how one could contain a "metaphorical intersection". And I think I can say I am a fairly sophisticated reader. While I encourage you to have fun with answers, I think much of this is meaningless, especially to most English learners, so I need to downvote the answer in its present form.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @JimReynolds. I can appreciate how a sophisticated reader might get confused by word pictures. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word+picture Do you notice the contradiction between your two comments? I labeled the **less** useful options as **less useful**, explaining why they would be less useful, while encouraging learners to explore how the metaphorical application of words and phrases actually works. You never **need** to downvote an answer, but you are certainly free to ignore the three patently useful expressions at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change the formula, *That was a ____________!*

*[Test from hell:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hell)*

> informal
>
> 6. An extremely unpleasant or troublesome example of something:
>
> **OED**

Comment: Absolutely. +1. But change what formula?

Comment: The formula of the original question was: The [test] was a ________.

Answer (score 2):

> The test was a killer.

"Killer" is an informal noun and adjective meaning something that is extremely difficult to deal with.

[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/killer)
[merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/killer)
[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/killer)

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Hall, [*A Collection of College Words and Customs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u1EXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22taking+a+screw%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UljYVOX6LMr1oASQwYK4Cw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20a%20screw%22&f=false) (1851) offer the evocative idioms "screw" and "taking a screw":

> SCREW. In some American colleges, an excessive, unnecessarily minute, and annoying examination of a student by an instructor is called a *screw*. The instructor is often designated by the same name. An imperfect recitation is sometimes thus denominated. [Examples dating back to 1832 omitted.]
>
> Passing such an examination is often denominated *taking a screw*. [Example omitted.]

Comment: My first thought upon discovering this usage was, "I wonder if prison guards were named _screws_ in honor of this type of instructor?"

Answer (score 0):

*[Dog's breakfast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dog%27s+breakfast)* follows the food theme to express displeasure in the results:

> a mess or muddle,
>
> a dog's breakfast or dog's dinner originally may have referred to a
> cooking mishap with results fit only for a dog's consumption.
>
> **thefreedictionary.com**

Comment: That's colorful, but doesn't mean *tough*.

Answer (score 0):

> **ACID TEST** *noun*:
>
> a severe or crucial test; a difficult situation or task that shows if someone or something is good enough to succeed
>
> [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acid%20test)

Answer (score 0):

**inquisition**

Merriam-Webster's definition 3.c for this noun is listed as:

> a severe questioning

In my experience, this word describes a very pointed interrogation where your answers may very well determine your future with regards to your status, freedom, or even your life! While this word does have specific implications in history and in the law (See MW's definitions 2 and 3.a), and is normally is used in the context of investigations of some sort rather than an examination, there is no explicit reason why it *shouldn't* be used in this context that I am aware of, and if you want to convey a tone of severity that borders on hyperbole, this might be apropos, particularly since MW's definition 3.b is:

> an investigation conducted with little regard for individual rights

Sometimes a brutal exam can leave you feeling that way!

Comment: This answer needs support from reputable sources.